# How to setup in `~/.vimrc` a mapping for `colorscheme` to toggle `solarized` between `dark` and `light`?

Tags: vimscript, colorscheme, plugin-solarized

Both *background* and *colorscheme* in `~/.vimrc` are badly misbehaving!

I have setup *solarized* to work on *vim* and it can manually toggle between *background* *light*/*dark*. My general settings in `~/.vimrc` are:

```
Plug 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized' "I use plug.vim
syntax enable
set background=light
set t_Co=256
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
```

Operating system: *Ubuntu 14.04.*; *xterm* and works well with 256 colors.

I'm trying to map in `~/.vimrc` background toggling. For this purpose :help solarized (in vim) suggests to use:

```
call togglebg#map("<F9>")
```

but this doesn't work because it changes the *colorscheme* from *solarized* to default (my intention was to toggle only in *solarized* between *dark* and *light*).

So I remove from `~/.vimrc call togglebg#map("<F9>")` and replaced it with what most google/superuser/vim.wikia commentators, in various flavors, have suggested with the following:

```
function! BgToggleSol()
    if (&background == "light")
      set background=dark 
    else
       set background=light 
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <leader>sz :call BgToggleSol()<cr>

colorscheme solarized
```

But this has the same problem (that toggling resets *colorscheme* to *default*). While if *colorscheme solarized* is executed directly after `set background=...` in the `if else endif` clause then the *background* stops toggling between *dark*/*light*.

I must have exhausted nearly all possibilities, but the problem is still not going away.

Any suggestion is very welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Something is definitely not right.
I have in my .vimrc something like this:

```
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
```

And when I do `:set bg?` after that, it shows "light".
I think that's the reason the if/else/endif in you function doesn't work after 'colorsheme solarized'.

The only workaround I can think of is to maintain the state in a separate variable:

```
" Initially set it to "dark" or "light" according to your default
let s:mybg = "dark"
function! BgToggleSol()
    if (s:mybg ==? "light")
       set background=dark
       let s:mybg = "dark"
    else
       set background=light
       let s:mybg = "light"
    endif
    " set background=light
    colorscheme solarized
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <leader>sz :call BgToggleSol()<cr>
```

Comment: Hmmm. What does `:verbose set background` report?

Comment: Thanks Boris Serebrov! It certainly is working. It's really nice and it's making so much difference in quality of work!

Comment: There is still a small nuance that's bugging me. The mapping togs well between dark/light using the script you drop earlier (now in my ~/.vimrc). The problem now (really a small issue) is that when I manually execute `:set background?` does not give always the right answer: it might be really a light screen and the cmdline reports dark and vice versa. Any suggestion why that might be and how to fix it please?

Comment: @Rich the `:verbose set background` says `Last set from ~/.vim/plugged/vim-colors-solarized/colors/solarized.vim` and this also confirms that calling `colorscheme solarized` also changes the background.

Comment: @AnnisMonadjem my solution is a workaround to the problem of `background` being set incorrectly. I would also prefer it to have correct value and then your initial code would just work and additional `mybg` variable would be not needed. I think you can try to report this issue to the vim-colors-solarized developers, maybe they will be able to fix it.

Comment: @AnnisMonadjem Also worth noting that this answer doesn't attempt to address the weird issue of what is setting your `colorscheme` back to `default` when `background` is set from a function (but not when you set it manually). It works around this issue, too.

Comment: @Rich actually for me `colorscheme` resets back to `default` even when set manually. I start with dark background and solarized scheme, the `:set bg?` reports `background=light`. If I then do `set background=dark` the colorscheme resets to `default`.

Comment: @BorisSerebrov Ah, okay. Even so, it's still weird! I don't know of any mechanism that could cause that, so I'd love to find out what's doing so.

Comment: @Rich actually it looks like a vim behavior, even if I start it as `vim -u NONE -U NONE`, the colorscheme still resets to default when I change the background between dark and light. Update: it is true only for terminal vim, colorscheme doesn't resets in gvim.

Comment: @BorisSerebrov Oh yes, there it is in `:h 'background'`. Not sure how I missed that before!

Answer (score 1):

You might want something like:

```
map <Leader>bg :let &background = ( &background == "dark"? "light" : "dark" )<CR>
```

This toggles between `dark` and `light`.
`Leader`'s default, if not set otherwise, is <kbd>\</kbd>.

Btw you can also do so with colorschemes:

```
map <Leader>cs :execute ( g:colors_name == "selenized_bw" ? "colorscheme selenized" : "colorscheme selenized_bw" ) <CR>
```

Or together:

```
noremap <Leader>bg :let &background = ( &background == "dark" ? "light" : "dark" )<CR> <bar> :execute ( g:colors_name == "selenized_bw" ? "colorscheme selenized" : "colorscheme selenized_bw" ) <CR>
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Thank you! What a nice surprise! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative two parter answer, that toggles **both** the colorscheme and the background. First, using your mapping, then a specific mapping pattern I use to mirror another popular plugin with many provided toggles.

This mapping toggles both the background to light or dark, and the colorscheme, using `printf`.

1. I'll use your `<leader>sz` mapping here:

   ```
   nnoremap <silent><expr><leader>sz printf(":set bg=%s \| colo %s\r", &bg ==# 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark', &bg ==# 'dark' ? 'modest' : 'moonfly')
   ```

Note that this uses `<expr>` in addition to your `<silent>` and this is required since we're using `printf`. Read `:help <expr>`

2. I use tpope's [vim-unpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) which advertises itself as "Pairs of handy bracket mappings" but it also provides many toggles that use a `yo_` mapping.

   So I set my colorscheme toggle to use the same pattern:

   ```
   nnoremap <silent><expr>yot printf(":set bg=%s \| colo %s\r", &bg ==# 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark', &bg ==# 'dark' ? 'modest' : 'moonfly')
   ```

   For some other examples of toggles, because why not, here's the list from [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) and **note that I am overwriting their colorcolumn toggle because I didn't realize it when I started using `yot` and evidently I never toggle that column**:

   ```
   On  Off Toggle  Option
   *[ob*   *]ob*   *yob*   'background' (dark is off, light is on)
   *[oc*   *]oc*   *yoc*   'cursorline'
   *[od*   *]od*   *yod*   'diff' (actually |:diffthis| / |:diffoff|)
   *[oh*   *]oh*   *yoh*   'hlsearch'
   *[oi*   *]oi*   *yoi*   'ignorecase'
   *[ol*   *]ol*   *yol*   'list'
   *[on*   *]on*   *yon*   'number'
   *[or*   *]or*   *yor*   'relativenumber'
   *[os*   *]os*   *yos*   'spell'
   *[ot*   *]ot*   *yot*   'colorcolumn' ("+1" or last used value)
   *[ou*   *]ou*   *you*   'cursorcolumn'
   *[ov*   *]ov*   *yov*   'virtualedit'
   *[ow*   *]ow*   *yow*   'wrap'
   *[ox*   *]ox*   *yox*   'cursorline' 'cursorcolumn' (x as in crosshairs)
   ```

   tpope comments on why they chose `y`: *"The mnemonic for y is that if you tilt it a bit it looks like a switch."*